# How to store data from a multidimensional array meta-box with multiple inputs in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my custom post-type, I am building an multi dimensional array meta-box with multiple `input`s, with below code:

```
<?php
    $services = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'services', true);

    foreach ((array) $services as $service) {
        echo '<div class="inside">
        <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="service[][title]" value="' . $service['title'] . '">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Type</label>
         <input type="text" name="service[][type]" value="' . $service['type'] . '">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea name="service[][text]">' . $service['text'] . '</textarea>
        </div>';
    }
    exit;
    ?>
```

And, saving the data with below function:

```
function service_save_meta_box_data($post_id) {
// verify taxonomies meta box nonce
if (!isset($_POST['service_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['service_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
    return;
}

// return if autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return;
}

// Check the user's permissions.
if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
    return;
}

// store custom fields values
// Feature Title
if (isset($_REQUEST['services'])) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'services', sanitize_text_field($_POST['service']));
}
}

add_action('save_post_service', 'service_save_meta_box_data');
```

However, the data is not being stored and retrieved in the `input`s.
Where am I doing the mistake?

Comment: Is this set somewhere: `isset($_REQUEST['services'])`?

Comment: Yes, in as `if` condition in save data function.

Comment: You have 'service' and 'services'. Is that a problem maybe? Try to change that to `if (isset($_POST['service']))`

Comment: Can you print this $_POST['service'] ?

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['service']))` did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

Template

```
<?php /*
 Template Name: Customform
 */

 get_header()
 ?>
 <form id="Customform">
    <div class="inside">
        <div>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="service[][title]" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Type</label>
         <input type="text" name="service[][type]">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Content</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="get_data">
            <textarea name="service[][text]"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>

            <input type="button" id="test" value="send">
        </div>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {

        jQuery("#test").click(function(){
            console.log("test");    


            jQuery.ajax({
                     type : "POST",
                     dataType : "json",
                     url : "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                     data : jQuery("#Customform").serialize(),
                     success: function(response) {

                           alert("Your vote could not be added");
                           alert(response);
                        }
                });   

        });
    })
 </script>
 <?php get_footer();?>
```

Functions.php

```
    function  savemyformdata() {

        update_post_meta(34, 'services', $_POST['service']);

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'get_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_data', 'savemyformdata' );
```